# Protractor : Read Table contents

Tags: javascript, testing, protractor, end-to-end

I've been writing e2e tests for my angular js app and am unable to figure this out. I've got a table with data in it. I want to extract the first rows data.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><\td>
        <td><\td>
        <td><\td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I did this in protractors `elementExplorer` and it prints out the values of all 3 columns

```
element.all(by.repeater('item in items.list')).get(0).getText()
James
Byrne
1
```

If I do this, it prints out the first column value

```
element.all(by.repeater('item in items.list')).get(0).element(by.css('td')).getText()
WARNING - more than one element found for locator By.cssSelector("td") - the first result will be used
James
```

My Question is, how do I get the values of the other columns?

Comment: Did you consider giving each column a `name`, then using `by.name()` to grab the specific column after you have the first row (from `.get(0)`)?

Answer (score 11):

Use [`all()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder) in conjunction with [`map()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.map):

```
var row = element.all(by.repeater('item in items.list')).first();
var cells = row.all(by.tagName('td'));

var cellTexts = cells.map(function (elm) {
    return elm.getText();
});
```

Then, you can assert it to be an array of column texts:

```
expect(cellTexts).toEqual(["The first text", "The second text", "The third text"]);
```

Comment: Thanks alexcxe. That worked. How do I get individual elements of cellTexts. For example I want to extract "The second text".  Also "The third text" happens to be the text of a button which I'd like to click.

Comment: @JDunn you can use `get()`: `expect(cellTexts.get(1)).toEqual("The second text");`. If you need to locate the button in the third td: `cells.get(2).element(by.tagName("button")).click();`. Hope it helps.

Comment: I get a Failed: undefined is not a function for cellTexts.get(1), the button clicking part worked well though

Comment: @JDunn what about `expect(cellTexts[1]).toEqual("The second text");`? Thanks.

Comment: Expected undefined to equal 'The second text'

Answer (score 10):

Easiest way would be as below:

```
var tabledata = element.all(by.css("./table"));

// get rows 
var rows = tabledata.all(by.tagName("tr"));

// get cell values
var cells = rows.all(by.tagName("td"));

expect(cells.get(0).getText()).toEqual("something")
expect(cells.get(1).getText()).toEqual("something")
expect(cells.get(2).getText()).toEqual("something")
```

I implemented it and it is working for me.